# Progress Bar Salesforce Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-experience

There is a huge list on which DML will be happening on click of certain button. While the DML is happening, I need to show the progress bar. I got the progress bar component in Lightning Design Systems. However, is there a way I can get number of records which are processed/yet to be processed or something like, 10 records processed out of 100. please suggest if someone has faced same.

```
<aura:attribute **name="scale"** type="Integer" default="0"></aura:attribute>
<div class="slds-progress-bar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="25" role="progressbar">
  <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width: 15%;">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 25%</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

All I want do here is , pass the integer value and show the progress bar. That Integer attribute -**Scale** needs to be obtained dynamically from salesforce based on number of items processed/processing.

Comment: Are you doing these DML in a single transaction? I mean in a single server call?

Comment: @NavalSharma thats correct. The DML will be happening in single transaction.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to fetch the information about the number of executed DML statements until your method's execution finished due to synchronous nature of server calls. You can achieve it by breaking your transaction in multiple transactions but that would affect the performance of the page.